# Need help understanding mongo query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Can anyone explain me this mongodb query: -

```
@Query("{'$or':[{owner:?0, companyId:?1, status:?2},{companyId:?1, membersDetails:{'$elemMatch':{memberId:?0, status:?2}}}]}")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Spring Data annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based) that will be attached to a method signature something like this:

```js
@Query("{'$or':[{owner:?0, companyId:?1, status:?2},{companyId:?1, membersDetails:{'$elemMatch':{memberId:?0, status:?2}}}]}")
List<MyClass> findByClassThings(String owner, String companyId, String status);
```

Or whatever the method is actually called as also with the appropriate types.

The query would act on data in storage something like this:

```js
{
    "owner": "A",
    "companyId": "B",
    "status": "C",
    "membersDetails": [
        { "memberId": "B", "status": "X" },
        { "memberId": "C", "status": "C" },
    ]
},
{
    "owner": "B",
    "companyId": "B",
    "status": "C",
    "membersDetails": [
        { "memberId": "A", "status": "C" }
    ]
}
```

So when that method was called with something like this:

```js
List<MyClass> results = MyClass.findByClassThings("A","B","C");
```

It would match both of those documents for the following reasons:

- The first document matches because the elements in "owner", "companyId" and "status" match all of the supplied parameters as specified in the first query element to the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) expression:

  ```js
  {owner:"A", companyId:"B", status:"C"}`
  ```
- The second document matches because the fields supplied are all present in the second query element of the `$or` condition. Being "companyId" is present at the top of the document and "status" is a match for an array element that also have the "memberId" with the same matching value to the first parameter:

  ```js
  {companyId:"B", membersDetails:{'$elemMatch':{memberId:"A", status:"C"}}}
  ```

In the later case [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) requires that "both" the conditions "must" be present within the array elements being queried for a single element.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
db.collection.find({$or: [{'owner': ?0, 'companyId': ?1, status:?2}, {'companyId': ?1, 'membersDetails': {'$elemMatch':{memberId:?0, status:?2}}}]});
```

Thanks